# Fails to insert records with stored procedure in php

Tags: php

I have the next code and i have experimented problems to insert in the data base, the   stored procedure works properly:

**The store procedure is:**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE newProduct

(   
IN tipo VARCHAR(10),
IN categoria VARCHAR(10),
IN marca VARCHAR(10),
IN modelo VARCHAR(10),
IN color VARCHAR(10),
IN talla DOUBLE,
IN corte VARCHAR(15),
IN cveprecio VARCHAR(20),
IN precio DECIMAL(7,2),
IN sugp DECIMAL(7,2)        
)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO tipos (tipo) VALUES (tipo);
INSERT INTO marcas (marca,modelo) VALUES (marca,modelo);
INSERT INTO colores (color) VALUES (color);
INSERT INTO tallas (talla) VALUES (talla);
INSERT INTO corte (corte) VALUES (corte);
INSERT INTO precios (cveprecio,precio,sugp) VALUES (cveprecio,precio,sugp);

COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Call to store procedure in MYSQL (It works)**

call newProduct('Tenis','Hombre','Nike','ACG90','Negro',26.5,'Sintetico','6p90',690.50,750.50);

**Code PHP for Connect to the DB**

```
<?php//connect.php
$connect= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','xxxx','bancodedatos');
if (!$connect)
{
printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server.", mysqli_connect_error());
exit;
}
?>
```

**Code for insert and call store procedure**

```
<?php//insert.php
include("../connect.php");
$tipo= isset($_POST['tipo']) ? $_POST['tipo'] : NULL;
$categoria= isset($_POST['categoria']) ? $_POST['categoria'] : NULL;
$marca= isset($_POST['marca']) ? $_POST['marca'] : NULL;
$modelo= isset($_POST['modelo']) ? $_POST['modelo'] : NULL;
$color= isset($_POST['color']) ? $_POST['color'] : NULL;
$talla= isset($_POST['talla']) ? $_POST['talla'] : NULL;
$corte= isset($_POST['corte']) ? $_POST['corte'] : NULL;
$cveprecio= isset($_POST['cveprecio']) ? $_POST['cveprecio'] : NULL;
$precio= isset($_POST['precio']) ? $_POST['precio'] : NULL;
$sugp= isset($_POST['sugp']) ? $_POST['sugp'] : NULL;
$createProduct=mysqli_query($connect,"CALL newProduct($tipo,$categoria,$marca,$modelo,$color,$talla,$corte,$cveprecio,$precio,$sugp)"); 

mysql_close ($connect);

?>
```

***To call it from php doesn't insert into database, thanks, and greetings from mexico***

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$createProduct=mysqli_query($connect,"CALL newProduct($tipo,$categoria,$marca,$modelo,$color,$talla,$corte,$cveprecio,$precio,$sugp)");
```

To

```
$createProduct=mysqli_query($connect,"CALL newProduct('$tipo','$categoria','$marca','$modelo','$color','$talla','$corte','$cveprecio','$precio','$sugp')");
```

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for escaping `'` and `"` in value of variable

Comment: thank you very much friend, I just change the line of code, and it works fine. but could you give me an example explained mysqli_real_escape_string (), please

Comment: One more question please, is the correct way to insert the data with store procedures, Any books you recommend? (if O'Reilly or Wrox is better), To implement it with jquery needs something changed, thanks again

Comment: if `$categoria = "Cat's Parry"`, then breaks your SP Call like `CALL newProduct('$tipo','Cat's Parry','$marca','$modelo','$color','$talla','$corte','$cveprecio','$precio','$sugp')`

Comment: so good to use mysqli_real_escape_string($categoria) so it will `Cat\' Parry`